# MVC3 :a required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I redirect a page from web form page(**profile.aspx**) to MVC view (**signin.aspx**). In MVC controller, I have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to get token information, but when I submit MVC view, I get **'a required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid'** message. If I remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, there is no more error message, but I lose my token information.
I do need all those token information for validation. So how can I fix this kind of issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<s>In your view, where you declare `<form>` you need to use @Html.AntiForgeryToken() helper.</s>

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    // The rest of your code
    <div class="something">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Whatever)
    </div>

    // etc...
}
```

This will pass anti-forgery token back to your controller.

UPDATE: The problem that you have is that you are performing redirection. WHen you do this all the values are lost. What is unclear is why you do the redirect from one page to another. Normally in MVC if user is not authenticated or session expires there will be a redirect to the login.aspx page. If your Signin.aspx is in `AccountController` then both Signing.aspx and AccountController should be marked for anti-forgery. However, if a user is in Signin.aspx, then internally you just call `return RedirectToAction("Profile", "WhateverController");` you information will be lost and `WhateverController` will fail because Profile action does not receive anti-forgery information.

Your sign-in process should do something, redirect to HTTP GET version of Profile, have user complete the form entry and submit it to HTTP POST version of Profile. THis way your data will be kept and anti-forgery token will arrive successfully.

Comment: See my update. Also, could you expand your question to explain clearly your process? Which controller handles profile.aspx, when redirecting where exactly do you redirect? Same controller? Different controller?

Comment: So how can I keep all token information? or after it redirect to MVC, how can I get all token inoformation from MVC? Thank.

Comment: Under which conditions do you perform redirect from Profile.aspx to Signin.aspx?

Comment: I have a profile web form page,and redeem code MVC view page. when a user login to website, if he didn't register before, it will redirect him to redeem page rather than showing his profile. After he enter the code,then redirect back to profile page. My problem is after enter the code,and click submit, it throw me this error message.

Comment: See my update. It will help you figure out how to reorganize your code a bit better.